# How do I find these links in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, ssl

I am running the latest version of wordpress and just installed SSL. I have also used SSL insecure content plug in. However, I am trying to find 3 items that are eluding me. I have also gone into phpmyadmin and changed all links from http to https using the replace feature. I am using elementor and woocommerce. Any guidance or help will be greatly appreciated.

Here are the current mixed content errors:

Mixed Content - Errors

Soft Failure
An image with an insecure url of "http://www.llamachula.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/peppers.jpg" was loaded on line: 458 of https://www.llamachula.com/.
This URL will need to be updated to use a secure URL for your padlock to return.
Soft Failure
An image with an insecure url of "http://blushing-oryx.w5.wpsandbox.pro/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/about-bg.png" was loaded on line: 458 of https://www.llamachula.com/.
This URL will need to be updated to use a secure URL for your padlock to return.
Soft Failure
A file with an insecure url of "http://oops.wpsandbox.io/expired-install/" was loaded on line: 468 of https://www.llamachula.com/.
This URL will need to be updated to use a secure URL for your padlock to return.

Answer (score 0):

Below is everything I thought of to check:

- If you're using [really simple ssl](https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/) (that's the most popular SSL redirection plugin and the one I would recommend) make sure you go into the settings and turn on the .htaccess redirect option.
- Make sure there is nothing in your .htaccess file that is redirecting to the HTTP version of the page.
- Use a search and replace tool such as [this one](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) to replace http://youromdomain with https://yourdomain in the database.
- If the following constants are defined in your wp-config.php file, make sure they are using https:

  ```
  define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://example.com' );
  define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com' );
  ```
- You shouldn't have to worry about this if you have an .htaccess file that redirects everything to https, but you can also check for plugins or theme that have hard-coded in an asset to load via HTTP. A good place to look is the header.php file of your theme, and if you SSH into the server, you can easily find where the problematic assets are being loaded by doing a grep search (`grep -r "your search term"`) to search the codebase. Ideally everything should be enqueued or for images they should be added through a WordPress function, but if not, then fix the problematic assets and notify the plugin/theme developers that they are adding their assets wrong.
- After doing all of the above, make sure you clear out any caches. This may include your Browser cache, Cloudflare/CDNs cache, Varnish cache, page level cache, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem is:

```
wp-content\uploads\elementor\css\post-405.css`

.elementor-motion-effects-layer {
    background-image:url("http://blushing-oryx.w5.wpsandbox.pro/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/about-bg.png");
}
```

There it is =)